# Read SOAP Message and insert the data into a variable

Tags: c#, xml, soap

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://webservice.someWebService.php">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:loginResponse>
            <return>
                <errorCode>OK</errorCode>
                <header>
                    <sessionToken>tokentokentokentokentokentokentokentokentoken</sessionToken>
                    <errorCode>OK</errorCode>
                </header>
            </return>
        </ns1:loginResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am trying to get the sessionToken from the XML above and place it into a string variable.

This is the code that i have tried:

```
            string soapmessage = response.Content;

            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml(soapmessage);  //loading soap message as string 
            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);

            manager.AddNamespace("d", "http://someURL");
            manager.AddNamespace("bhr", "https://webservice.someWebService.php");

            XmlNodeList xnList = document.SelectNodes("//bhr:loginResponse", manager);
            int nodes = xnList.Count;
            string Status;
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                Status = xn["d:sessionToken"].InnerText;
            }
```

But im getting an error of
**`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to do this:

```
string Status = xnList[0]["return"]["header"]["sessionToken"].InnerText;
```

The sessionToken is not directly under the first node, so attempting to access it will return `null`, and calling `.InnerText` on `null` will result in NullReferenceException.

Comment: This mean I need to state each of the node that shows the path to the sessionToken right?

Comment: Yes, that looks like the easiest way, if the path is always the same. If the path changes, it gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: Do you have any references that I can look at and learn?

Comment: I think the examples here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-5.0#navigate-the-document-tree will be useful in getting a good understanding. Also the next section on the same page, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-5.0#find-nodes